# Insertion sort in ruby

Tags: ruby, insertion-sort

The code is correct, passes all testcases, I am looking for input on cleaning it, readability etc

```
def  insertionSort(a) 
    return if a.nil? || a.empty? || a.length == 1
    sort_index = 0
    for i in 1..a.length-1 do
        for j in 0..sort_index do
            next if a[i] > a[j] 
            temp = a[i]
            sort_index.downto(j) do |n|
               a[n+1] = a[n] 
            end    
            a[j] = temp            
        end
        sort_index +=1      
    end
  a  
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858611/1623261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby tends to use two spaces for indents, rather than four.

Avoid `for`; it's very uncommon in Ruby and, while technically correct, doesn't make full use of Ruby's functionality. In the general case, you can replace

```
for a in b do
```

with

```
a.each do |b|
```

and the rest of the code is (probably) identical. For this case, however, since you're iterating over a range of integers, I'd suggest using `upto`:

```
1.upto(a.length-1) do |i|
  0.upto(sort_index) do |j|
```

Or, if you feel like you really should have `for a in b` or `b.each do |a|`, you can use `1...a.length` to exclude the last element, instead of subtracting one.

Use more informative variable names -- `i` and `j` might make sense to you now, but it's rather difficult to understand if you don't already know how insertion sort works.

I don't see a difference between `sort_index` and `i - 1`, though I haven't had a chance to run it and test it yet.

You should return `a` if `a.length == 1`, not nothing, since sorting a 1-item array is still sorting. Because the sort won't do anything, you can just remove the check entirely from the first `if` and forget about it.

Sorts in Ruby should use `<=>` instead of `<` or `>` because `<=>` is the universal comparison operator. See [the docs for `Object#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

1. Method names should have words separated by underscores instead of using camelCase to follow standard naming conventions: `def insertion_sort(a)`
2. I've got a love-hate relationship with single letter variable names. In some contexts, such as this method, it *might* be OK, because the method name could infer what `a` means, but consider changing the argument name to `array_to_sort` or `sort_array`. This isn't necessarily an official naming convention, but I've seen many Ruby developers use `arr` in these situations, though arguably `arr` isn't much better than `a`.
3. The `return if ...` line will return nil if the array is nil, doesn't have any values or contains one value. Consider this scenario:

   ```
   arr = [1]
   arr = insertion_sort(arr)
   ```

   This will result in `arr` being set to a `nil` value, which doesn't seem right. This would be better written as:

   ```
   def insertion_sort(a)
     raise ArgumentError, "Cannot pass a nil value" if a.nil?
     return a if a.empty? || a.length == 1

     ...
     a
   end
   ```

   This keeps the return value of this method consistent. Additionally, passing a `nil` value is an "exceptional" condition. You cannot insert or sort a nil value, so an `ArgumentError` should be thrown here.

   After that, if the array is empty or contains just one element, just return the array early before performing the insertion sort.

Comment: A bit late, but I think `arr` is significantly better than `a`. I mean, it sounds all pirate-y.